# node.js 0.12.x memory usage

Tags: node.js, performance, memory

Trying to upgrade my application from node 0.10.x to node 0.12.x family, I was hit with an unpleasant surprise: 0.12 uses about 15%-20% more RAM than 0.10.

Judging by a [few](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/823) [threads](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/856) on io.js issues page, it seems the fault lies with the underlying v8 engine.

Now software update is a difficult proposition to sell to management as it is. Add to that the need to pay for more VPS hardware with few visible benefits, and this becomes a deal breaker for us.

Is there a way to disable whatever new bells & whistles v8 had added that are taking up the additional RAM? Perhaps the touted CPU profiling stuff?

I'm basically looking for a v8 switch that can reduce memory usage to the level comparable to the v8 shipped with node 0.10.

Comment: How does io.js fare against 0.10 in your application?

Comment: I just tried to test it, but was hit with a bunch of unresolved npm issues (node-gyp incompatibility). I gave up at that point, even if I could make it work on this one test system, it doesn't seem like something I can rely on in production.

Comment: Please consider opening issues against bugs you run into in io.js, I think that whatever performance hits you got over 0.10 you can win by using generators instead of closures for async operations which is faster. Also - did you actually lose performance or just memory usage? (As in, given the same amount of available system ram - does it also serve 15% less requests?)

Comment: Rewriting the whole application is not feasible. Maybe an idea for a future project. It's hard to judge performance. It's not a public-facing app, so there's no easy metric such as request rate. But performance seems fine on 0.12. Most of our pressure is on memory not CPU, which is why this is so bad.

Comment: Right, but did you actually benchmark it in a real use case? It's entirely possible that v8 is just preallocating stuff and can clean it up and use as much (or even less) memory when the time comes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. The way I found out about this problem was when linux kernel started killing the nodes that used to work near the edge of their VPS memory allotment. If t here's a preallocated cache, v8 obviously isn't able to let it go.

Comment: We've seen the same memory increase.  io.js and 0.12 show very similar memory profiles - not surprising, since they pick up the same v8 changes that seem to have caused this.

Comment: @panta82 I already faced this issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692891/nodejs-why-pm2-list-shows-memory-keeps-on-increasing.. Using 0.12.2 and  HAPI 8^. I degraded my node server to 0.10.36 (Stable)

Comment: We also had this issue, it's right at the limit for us so the nodes are not being killed, but still an issue.  How did the max-old-pace-size work for you?

Answer (score 8):

You can limit the amount of memory your Node.js process uses with the [`--max-old-space-size`](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-memory-limit-on-a-node-process) flag. Perhaps you can cap the memory at something acceptable and then benchmark your app to see if it performs acceptably.

```
node --max-old-space-size=512 myScript.js
```

I believe there are also flags that control garbage collection that might be worth exploring. And [this GitHub issue about v8 performance profiling etc.](https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf/issues/4) may be worth your time reading as well.

Comment: `--max-old-space-size` switch is used to increase the max memory of a node process above 512mb. It doesn't seem to do anything if set below that value, and even if it did, I don't see how it would help (except cause a crash). I know about performance profiling stuff, the issue is that the same code uses different amount of RAM on different runtimes. So there's something in the V8 itself that takes the extra space, not the code I can profile.

Answer (score 0):

If reverting back the v.10 is an option for you, you can do that very easily using [Node Version Manager NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Just switch to any version you like on the go and use it, while waiting for a fix for v.12.

Comment: That's what I did. It's not the real solution I was looking for, though.